# If an object is travelling near light speed, would it's actions seem to be in slow motion?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, time, time-dilation

Hypothetically if we were observing a clock travelling near light speed relative to us, we would see the clock ticking at a much slower speed than us. If that is true, then would all actions that are *at rest relative to the clock* seem to be slower too? For example if the clock were to explode, would we observe the explosion to be a slower speed?

If my question doesn't make sense then please ask for clarification I'm having trouble putting my thoughts into words.

Comment: SR time dilation isn't hypothetical is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From our point of view (our reference frame) - we, who observe a clock traveling near light speed relative to us - *all* events are much slower - so the clock explosion is much slower, too. It's a fact.

(The only problem is *how to observe* this wonderful slow clock explosion in an object passing us with so enormous speed. :-))

Answer (score 1):

Due to time dilation , any system that would be moving with speeds near to the speed of light, would be slower. All actions would take longer time.
But if you were inside that system, ie also moving with speeds comparable to that of light, you will observe everything normal in your spaceship but the people on earth will appear to go slower for you